# Splitting the German word "Taucherausrüstung"

Tags: etymology

I mean splitting into prefix, suffix, and so on. Like when you look at the etymology. 
For example:

> Gelegenheit

is:

> Ge+ legen + heit

To better understand some German words I'm trying to split them. Usually is easy using a dictionary or looking at the etymology but I couldn't achieve this with the following word:

> Taucherausrüstung

Comment: [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Taucherausruestung) should be helpful here.

Comment: @Baz: mmm.. by splitting I mean like splitting beraten to be and raten. Splitting into prefix, words, suffix and so on..

Comment: Not sure I understand. It's a composition of `Taucher` (diver) and `Ausrüstung` (gear).

Comment: Would you like to ask about the Rindfleisch­etikettierungs­überwachungs­aufgaben­übertragungs­gesetz too?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Note: I'm afraid the service that I linked to is no longer available. LEO has taken over some features of canoo.net but not the one about word formation.

---

You get the ultimate answer to your question using [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/taucherausr%C3%BCstung:N:F).

[image]

You read this diagram starting from the right end:
The word *Taucherausrüstung* is a composition noun+noun (i.e. *Taucher* and *Ausrüstung*).
The noun *Taucher* is derived from the verb *tauchen* with the suffix *[-er](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/er.html?country=D#Anchor-Verb-14210)*. The verb cannot be segmented any further.
The noun *Ausrüstung* is derived from the verb *ausrüsten* with the suffix *[-ung](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/ung.html?country=D#Anchor-Verb-23240)*.
The verb *ausrüsten* is derived from the verb *rüsten* (which cannot be segmented any more) with the prefix *[aus-](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-V/Praefixe/aus.html)*.

Comment: Thi site is simply wonderful!!!

Comment: But the result is not the splitting ;D

Comment: +1 That site is brilliant.

Comment: It seems that unfortunately canoo.net no longer works as it used to. I wonder if the feature is still available somewhere in the website (I don't speak enough German to find it), or if something similar is available elsewhere.

Comment: @anol No, that's no longer available :(
They say: "Die Technologie, die für die Wortbildung verwendet wurde, verblieb bei der IMTF. Diese Informationen sind daher bei LEO leider nicht in gleichem Umfang verfügbar. ...."

Answer (score 3):

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Taucherausruestung) has the answer:

> Ausrüstung für einen Taucher

`Taucherausrüstung` is a simple composition of `Taucher` (diver) and `Ausrüstung` (gear/equipment).

Comment: That is not what the Asker asked, he asked for the splitting, see my answer below.

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere It is what the OP asked for as you can tell from the comments to the question. Why else would s/he mark it as solved? Anyway, the "splitting" you are referring to can also be found on the Duden page I linked to...

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere No, OP did not ask for syllabification. OP tries to split up words to get a grasp of the meaning of a word.

Comment: Well, this is clearly wrong, so I'm not sure what he actually wants to know: Ge+ legen + heit

Comment: Eekk, can't edit the comment, oki again: Well, this 'splitting' is clearly wrong, so I'm not sure what he actually wants to know: Ge+ legen + heit. While Taucherausrüstung can be 'splitted' in a meaning full sense into two words: Taucher/diver and Ausrüstung/equipment, Gelegenheit can't be split like that. In fact it is "unsplittable" in the sense you propose as it is not a word that got combined from simple words.

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere OP assumed that "[ge-](http://www.canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Praefixe/ge.html)" is the prefix (not the case here) and "[-heit](http://www.canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/heit.html?country=D)" the suffix (is true). And legen (or rather liegen) is the root. Actually, "gelegen" is the participle adjective, thus the correct splitting is "gelegen + heit". Still, if you assume "ge" being the prefix, OP's splitting is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syllabification for [*Taucherausrüstung*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Taucherausruestung) is: Tau- cher- aus- rüs- tung.

Answer (score 0):

Taucher + Ausrüstung. tauch-en, Tauch-er. rüst-en, aus-rüsten, Aus-rüst-ung,

What was the difficulty in finding the elements of wordformation of this word?

Comment: mmmm... I've tried looking on many different dictionaries but but it wasn't so clear. It could have been: Taucheraus+rüstung or Tauch+erausrüstung. Everything is possible when you have no idea of how to split a word. For understanding how is that word for me try to read and split the following one معدات الغوص :-P

Comment: Now I understand  your problem. As a German one has to learn what problems for learners can arise.